# Move to next activity by button

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml

I new in WP development.

I have two XAML screens.

In first screen I have button, that want to get user to next screen.

How I can make this in xaml.cs file?

I know that in Android it like this

```
dostavka.Click += delegate
            {



                var intent145 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent145);
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer founded. It's simple

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName));
```